# How to cross compile C++ Gtkmm from Linux to Windows?

Tags: c++, linux, cross-compiling, gtkmm

For some time I was learning C++ and I was looking for some cross-platform, easy to use GUI and my choice was Gtkmm.

I've made my first app using Gtkmm under Linux for my company. It was smooth experience using glade. Under Linux everything worked fine, but when I started compiling it under Windows problems started to show up. Finally, after some code changes, I was able to compile it under Windows and it was "working".

Now I want to cross-compile it under Linux and it's just impossible. Every guide and post I've found is very old and information provided is not accurate, often with broken links and tools mentioned in them don't exist.

Has anyone had a similar experience? Making app took me few hours, while dealing with all this crap already wasted 2 weeks of my life and it is still not working.

How could I make this work?

Comment: https://linuxfromscratch.org/ could be relevant

Comment: Its long time since I did this, but a problem I had, was that some library required a native tool to run duiring build time. Running everything during windows build under msys under wine worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I have not yet done it myself, but I beleive the [Meson Build System](https://mesonbuild.com/index.html) could help you. Here is a [simple example](https://mesonbuild.com/Tutorial.html) using GTK. There are successful applications using it to cross compile between Linux and Windows, such as gedit. You can look at [their repo](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit) which is a good example.

It seems Gtkmm also has some example in [their repo](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtkmm-documentation/-/blob/gtkmm-3-24/meson.build).

Comment: Today as a last idea I tried reinstalling mingw toolchain and suprisingly it compiled.
Now I have linking problems with std library, I'll try to solve this tommorow.

Comment: Good to know. If you ever want to automate your procedure, take a look at Meson (or any other build system). It could help you.

Comment: I was always using make, but I might look into meson

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to cross-compile Gtkmm yourself, you can get prebuilt binaries from [MSYS2 repos](https://repo.msys2.org/mingw/x86_64/). Or, if you insist on building it yourself, you might want to look at MSYS2's [build scripts](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/) for it.

MSYS2's package manager doesn't run on Linux even under Wine, so you'll have to download the package and its dependencies manually.

Since this is too much work, I made [a small script](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2) that does it for you.

- Install `make`, `wget`, `tar`, `zstd`.
- `git clone https://github.com/holyblackcat/quasi-msys2`
- `cd quasi-msys2`
- Now you can search for the package: `make list-all | grep gtkmm`

  I see following packages available:

  ```
  mingw-w64-x86_64-gtkmm
  mingw-w64-x86_64-gtkmm3
  mingw-w64-x86_64-gtkmm4
  ```
- Let's install Gtkmm4: `make install _gtkmm4` (the `mingw-w64-x86_64-` prefix in package names can be replaced with `_`)

  This will download everything to the current directory. After the script is done, your library will be in `./root/`.

If you already have MinGW installed and are comfortable with using it, you can stop here.

But if not, this repo can also help with setting up cross-compilation with Clang (or MSYS2's GCC/Clang running under Wine, but they are too slow for any real-world use).

- Install Clang (the regular Linux version from your package manager; any distribution of Clang is capable of cross-compiling)
- Install Wine
- Determine how Clang binaries are named. If it's just `clang`, then do `export WIN_CLANG_VER=NONE`. If it's suffixed with a version, e.g. `clang-11`, do `export WIN_CLANG_VER=11`.
- `make install _gcc` because Clang needs MinGW's standard library (and other things) to cross-compile.
- Symlink `/mingw64` to the installation directory. (This is optional, but otherwise `pkg-config` for MSYS2 libraries might give you wrong paths, which may or may not be fixed by passing `--define-prefix` to it.)

  ```
  sudo ln -nfs "/<your path here>/quasi-msys2/root/mingw64" /mingw64
  ```
- `env/shell.sh` to open a new shell, with environment variables prepared for cross-compiling. Later you can `exit` to return to the original shell.

  This will perform some other initialization, and among other things it might ask you for the `sudo` password to temporarily configure the kernel to transparently run Windows executables with Wine. This is recommended but not strictly necessary, see readme if you want to avoid it.
- Copy-paste a hello world example from https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-helloworld.html.en
- I'm going to use pkg-config to obtain proper compiler and linker flags. First, we need to figure out how exactly Gtkmm is named in pkg-config:

  ```
  pkg-config --list-all | grep gtkmm
  ```

  This gives me:

  ```
  gtkmm-4.0                      gtkmm - C++ binding for the GTK+ toolkit
  ```
- Now you can build the example using `` win-clang++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-4.0` ... ``

  `win-clang++` is a wrapper around the native Clang provided by my repo, that adds the necessary cross-compilation flags to it.

  It seems Gtkmm uses C++17, so I also had to add `-std=c++17`.

  The command I ended up with is:

  ```
  win-clang++ helloworld.cc main.cc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-4.0` -std=c++17
  ```

  This spews out some warnings from Gtkmm headers, but successfully produces `a.exe`.
- Finally, run the resulting binary with `./a.exe`.

  The first time you use Wine after a reboot, starting an application might take a while, so be patient.

  Here's the result:

  [image: pic]

Comment: Thats mostly what I did. I had libs and headers from MSYS2. Code compiled after reinstalling mingw toolchain, but still have some linking peoblems. After I come back home I'll try clean msys2 install and get all rquired files again